# How to understand a situation where one can use Nakayama's lemma even when the situation is not Tailor-made.

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, local-rings, cayley-hamilton

In commutative algebra we have the following version of Nakayama's Lemma(also calle NAK lemma):

*NAK Lemma:*

> Let $R$ be a local ring and $\mathbf m$ be  the unique maximal ideal of $R$.Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module and $I\subset \mathbf m$ be an ideal of $R$ such that $IM=M$.Then $M=0$.

Another version is also useful sometimes:

*NAK Lemma:* **(Version $2.0$)**

> Let $M$ be  finitely generated $R$-modules where $(R,\mathbf m)$ is a local ring  and $N$ be an $R$-submodule of $M$ such that there exists $I\subset \mathbf m$ ideal of $R$ such that $M+IN=M$,then $M=N$.

Now it often happens that the situations for application of Nakayama's lemma is not Tailor-made and we have to identify a way so that we can make the situation required verbatim to use Nakayama's lemma.To be more precise my question is what are the signs I should look for,in order to get a hint that I have to use NAK lemma.This question is quite broad ended.I am not very experienced with NAK lemma and commutative algebra stuff.So,still situations of NAK lemma may not ring a bell,if the situation is not Tailor-made(i.e.if the ground for directly applying the theorem is not set already).Can anybody help me with understanding this thing better so that I can appreciate NAK lemma better and I can also apply NAK lemma in suitable situations while solving problems or doing algebra.

Comment: I like your "tailor-made"...

Comment: The statements of the Nakayama lemma you give are both missing the "finitely generated" assumption on $M$.

Comment: Sorry I missed it by chance.